# "Query" an Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, aggregate-functions

I have a situation where I have a large array with data from a database, some columns are dimensions (things that can be counted: year, city, state, etc) and others that can be summed (like population).

I'm trying to put the stress of manipulating that data on the PHP server rather than the database, even though SQL is ideally suited to send back the data a number of different ways.

So, let's say I need:

- Population by Year
- Population by City, State

I could (and have) loops and what not that will sum things up. What would be nice though, would be to leverage MySQL's simplicity when it comes to aggregating, grouping, etc:

`SELECT year, population FROM [array?]`

I guess more than anything I'm looking for recommendations on the best way to organize this kind of thing. Is there a PHP library that might help abstract some of this?

Comment: I know it's not a constructive answer, but why not use SQL for handling all data manipulation? It's faster than PHP in most cases and will return back a dataset exactly as you need

Comment: You might also look at ways of caching the results so you don't need to process them for each request which would might open up some advantages for you, but even so, you seem to acknowledge what you want to do is suited to SQL, so, err, using SQL seems to make more sense.

Comment: If you absolutely have to do this in a PHP array and not in your database, then look at [PHPLinq](https://phplinq.codeplex.com/) or any of the other Linq libraries for PHP; but a database is designed to handle that stress in a way that PHP is not

Comment: @Askanison4, manipulating the data with PHP is, believe it or not, faster than querying the data. One option I do have is to pull the raw data into a temporary table and aggregate from there; that might be faster and cleaner.

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks! I'll look into it. (And thanks for PHPExcel, it's the best!)

Comment: @Chords: I am curious as to the validity of your "PHP is faster" statement in that context. If that is true, either you have a very limited SQL server or you have a very small dataset. What happens when you have 100K rows? A million?

Comment: @mrunion I'm querying against a huge amount of data with a lot of joins, on a system that is often at capacity, so I'm trying to hit it only once and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPLinq, courtesy of @MarkBaker's comment.

https://phplinq.codeplex.com/

Other options, for anyone else with a similar problem:

- Depending on the database engine, joining everything into one query can be a good option, runtime permitting.
- Replicate/ETL and pull from the new source.